# Sql Stored Procedure returns an Old Result When Triggered From Vbs

Tags: vbscript, sql-server-2012

I have 2 stored procedures that work together. The first grabs the max value int from a single column table, and adds one to it in a new row each time the stored procedure is run.

The second stored procedure then concatenates that field with several others from a different table to create a long string that is stored in another table.

When run from SSRS, I get the **correct result every time** in the final table. When I trigger this from a vbs script on another server, the first stored procedure stores the new row as expected. However, the second stored procedure frequently ignores that new value, and uses the old max result in its concatenated string.

**My Vbs script:**

```
 Option Explicit

    Dim ObjConnection


    OpenADOObjects
    CloseADOObjects


    Sub OpenADOObjects

    Set ObjConnection=CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    ObjConnection.CommandTimeout = 360
    ObjConnection.Open ConnectionString()
    ObjConnection.Execute "exec dbo.**************"
    End Sub

    Sub CloseADOObjects
    ObjConnection.Close
    End Sub

    Function ConnectionString()
   ConnectionString="Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=********L;Database=******;Trusted_Connection=yes;UID=****;PWD=************"
    End Function`
```

Does anybody have any idea what might be happening here? I can't figure it out.

Comment: presumably you have a race issue, or are not re-reading the value after it's changed.

Comment: Could it still be a race issue if it still happens when I build in a 2 minute delay between the first and second stored procedure? The first procedure takes only a second to run.

Comment: No; in that case I suspect you are not reading the value  again...